# I have a confusion regarding strcpy() in c

Tags: c, structure, strcpy

I was writing push() operation for a stack where each item in the stack is a string, while doing so I wrote push operation as

```
void push(char *str)
{
  stack.top++;
  strcpy(stack.arr[stack.top],"");
  strcpy(stack.arr[stack.top],str);
}
```

where stack is a global variable of struct type

```
struct s
{
   char arr[30][40];;
   int top;
};

struct s stack;
```

to my surprise,I found the value of the stack elements always "" even after the push operation,
I then commented out the line

```
strcpy(stack.arr[stack.top],"");
```

and now the items in the stack contained the values that were in str correctly.

my question is why did the first approach which involved initializing the item first to null by an strcpy(item,""), followed by strcpy(item,str) not succeed in assigning the stack item with the value contained in str?

for those of you who wanted to see the entire code here it is..
and if you downvote my question, please let me know why,i didnt mention the code initially so as to make the question as concise as possible, i dont think i deserved that downvote

```
/*postfix to infix.working*/

#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>

struct s
{
    char arr[40][50];
    int top;
};

void post_to_in(char input[50]);
void push(char *str);
char* pop();
void init();

struct s stack;

int main(void)
{
    char input[50];

    printf("enter the input string\n");
    scanf("%s",input);

    init();

    post_to_in(input);

   /* printf("the infix expression is \n");
    printf("%s",output);*/
    return 0;
}

void post_to_in(char input[50])
{
    int len=0;
    int i;
    char buf[2];
    char *item1,*item2;

    for(i=0;input[i]!='\0';i++)
    {
        ;
    }
    len = i;
    /*abc, len =3 */

    for(i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        if(isalnum(input[i]))
        {
            sprintf(buf,"%c",input[i]);
            push(buf);
            continue;
        }

        /*if control here, implies input[i] is an operator*/
        item1 = pop();
        item2 = pop();

        sprintf(buf,"%c",input[i]);
        strcat(item2,buf);
        strcat(item2,item1);
        push(item2);
    }

    item1 = pop();

    printf("the infix expression is \n");
    printf("%s",item1);
}


void push(char *str)
{
    stack.top++;
    strcpy(stack.arr[stack.top],str);
}

char* pop()
{
    if(stack.top==-1)
    {
        printf("this shouldnt be happening\n");
        return "";
    }
    return stack.arr[stack.top--];
}

void init()
{
    stack.top =-1;
}
```

Comment: There shouldn't be any difference. The problem is elsewhere in the code.

Comment: It's very fishy-looking that you increment `top` *before* using it.

Comment: The first `strcpy` call is useless; its presence or absence should make no difference. The problem is in code you haven't shown us.

Comment: @unwind i hope it isnt "fishy" any more,

Comment: @KlasLindbäck , i know that the first line doesnt make a difference, i  asked the question because i was curious to know why the program didnt work when i included the redundant statement,just add the line to the code and although it shouldnt make any difference, when you compile you will see that it does make a difference. I am curious to know why, even i felt initially that it shouldnt make a difference, but am surprised to see that it does make a difference

Comment: Do you have some some input and the corresponding output?

Comment: Of course it doesn't make a difference. When I tried your prog with some input like "ljlkjlkjk" or "a*b" it produced stack underruns.

Comment: @PeterSchneider in the program, i have assumed that the input given is not erroneous like the inputs that you have given, the program works correctly when given proper inputs, it does not handle erroneous inputs, ...now my question is why does it fail for PROPER INPUTS when the strcpy(item,"") line is inserted

Comment: @PeterSchneider, dont down vote for such silly reasons...

Comment: I didn't, if you must know. I did upvote Klas' remark because it's obviously true, and after I tried out your program (!) and couldn't figure out what input it expects from comments (because there aren't any) or from your question, I upvoted R.Sahu's request for an input/output example. It would help if you'd provide one, perhaps we could figure out what magic happens. Withoug your assistance it will stall unsolved.

Comment: Apparently @KlasLindbäck solved it. Respect.

Comment: @Peter The function name `post_to_in` gave me a hint, and reading the code for that function gave additional insight. But I agree that the question could be clearer on that point. I used `34+` as sample input, getting `3+4` as output.

Comment: I understand that you are disappointed by downvotes, but I understand the downvoters as well. Let me explain why. As Klas observed correctly, there had to be an error elsewhere in the program. In other words you are saying "I have no idea what's happening here". Which means that anybody trying to help you had to dig through your code (which wasn't as frustrating as with some others', at least). That's quite a favour to you, so you really should help us by providig any assistance you can give. But you didn't provide a working program in the beginning, and you didn't give us a spec.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you `pop`, you return a pointer into the stack structure.

`item1` will point to `stack.arr[stack.top]`, so that when you push, you will overwrite the input.

The `push` also invokes undefined behaviour even if you don't have the extra `strcpy`, because the source and target strings of `strcpy` overlap (in fact, they are the same!).

The solution is to use a separate buffer when writing the infix expression:

```
    /*if control here, implies input[i] is an operator*/
    char buffer[50];   // Added this line
    item1 = pop();
    item2 = pop();

    /* Replaced code: 
    sprintf(buf,"%c",input[i]);
    strcat(item2,buf);
    strcat(item2,item1);
    push(item2);
    */
    // New code
    sprintf(buffer, "%s%c%s", item2, input[i], item1);
    push(buffer);
```

**Edit:**

Example to demonstrate the problem. Input string = `34+`:

Stack struct when we get the `+`:

```
top = 1
"3"   // stack.buf[0]
"4"   // stack.buf[1]
```

After that you `pop` into `item1` and `item2`.

```
item1 = pop();
item2 = pop();
```

Item1 and item2 now point into the stack struct:

```
top = -1
"3"   // stack.buf[0]  item2 points to this location
"4"   // stack.buf[1]  item1 points to this location
```

You then modify item 2. Before calling push, the stack struct will look like this:

```
top = -1
"3+4" // stack.buf[0]  item2 points to this location
"4"   // stack.buf[1]  item1 points to this location
```

Then you call push. `top` is changed to `0`.
Then `strcpy` is called, and if you first write "" then input gets overwritten and the stack struct will look like this:

```
top = 0
"" // stack.buf[0]  item2 points to this location - You push to this location, but the source string is at the same location!!!
"4"   // stack.buf[1]  item1 points to this location
```

Comment: `pop`ped strings get overwritten when a new value is `push`ed to the same location.